# Get DNS search suffix in Python

Tags: python, networking, dns, pywin32

Does anyone know how to get a list of DNS search suffixes on a client - both ones that have been manually added and ones assigned by DHCP. I'd prefer to have a cross-platform solution, but a Windows only solution will work. I couldn't find anything in pywin32 or other modules...

Comment: Please elaborate your problem and code of anything you already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of investigation, it doesn't look like there is a cross-platform way since the OS stores this information differently. On Windows, I ended up querying the information via the registry:

```
def getLocalDomainSuffix():
    domainSuffixSet = set()
    netKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\Tcpip\\Parameters')
    for keyName in ("DhcpDomain", "SearchList"):    
        value, type = _winreg.QueryValueEx(netKey, keyName)
        if value:
            for item in value.split(','):
                domainSuffixSet.add(item)
    return domainSuffixSet
```