# Getting DNS search domains in Python

Tags: python, dns

I want to get the search domains configured for localhost, meaning the domain names appended to hostnames when looking up DNS, such as `example.com` or `some.other.example.com`.

In Linux they are kept in `/etc/resolv.conf` like this:

```
search example.com some.other.example.com
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318427/get-dns-search-suffix-in-python) has an OS specific solution for Windows.

Is there a platform independent way of getting the host's DNS search domains in Python?

Comment: The answer you linked to says, "*it doesn't look like there is a cross-platform way*". It seems to me that answers your question.

Comment: The question was on Windows, and I was hoping that “doesn’t look like” meant there may exist another solution. It looks like you may be right though ;)